# SQL find ID by Sum of rates

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey cant find the right answer for my question.
If I have a table :

> DB :rate
>
> ```
> 1 id              int(11)     
> 2 type            varchar(256)    
> 3 candidate_id    int(11) 
> 4 data            text(rating data is inside here 1-10)
> ```

I want all Candidate_ids as result where the average rate is a search string for example 3. How can I get this happen? I tried it but cant get it on my own.
Every candidate has more than 5 Records in the DB:rate

```
id    type   candidate_id   data

 1    vote        5          10 
 2    vote        5           4    
 3    vote        4           4   
 4    vote        4           3    
 5    vote        5           8
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I think you want to dig into GROUP BY and HAVING clauses in SQL SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit difficult to follow. You want all Candidates with an average rate of 3, but your table doesn't feature a column "rate" - did you mean "data"? However, IF I got your question right, something like ( ! ) the following should solve the problem:

```
SELECT Candidate_ID
FROM [RateTable]
GROUP BY Candidate_ID
HAVING Avg(rate) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand the question, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT candidate_id   
FROM TableName
GROUP BY candidate_id   
HAVING AVG(data) = 3
```

Comment: thats what i am searching for, ty!